# Error when building wifi drivers on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: linux, makefile, wifi

I'm building the wireless driver from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.10.4/backports-3.10.4-1.tar.bz2 and I get this error message. 
I have build-essential and the generic headers installed.. not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated!

ipw2200.c:8259:4: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__list_for_each’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    __list_for_each(p, &priv->ibss_mac_hash[index]) {

Comment: Like K3--mc said, The new macro is `list_for_each` instead of `__list_for_each`. You could simply change it to that at the source code of the driver at line 8259.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel you are running (or the one you have includes for) is missing `__list_for_each` macro (AFAICT, last found in 3.10's `linux/list.h`, missing in 3.11 kernel).

Install 3.10 kernel (and associated headers) from repositories, reboot into it, and reconfigure.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the actual code in that line `__list_for_each` to `list_for_each` in 3.13.x which is referred by my `linux/list.h`